# problem with operators in Mysql `select` query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm new in `MySQL` and trying to filter users base on age, gender, and `chat_id`,

with below query:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE
age = 17
AND gender='$gender1' OR gender='$gender2'
AND chat_id <> '$chat_id'
LIMIT 1
```

when `$age` is 17, i get unexpected result and `$age` is not considered.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does "age = 17 doesn't working" mean? You get an error? unexpected results? What?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. 
 Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: i get unexpected result and age is not considered in final result

Comment: You probably need parentheses.

Comment: This is a question about logical evaluation. You _probably_ need some brackets around `(gender='$gender1' OR gender='$gender2')`...

Comment: where the code need parentheses?

Comment: Thank you. I added brackets and its worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
AND gender='$gender1' OR gender='$gender2'
```

to this:

```
AND (gender='$gender1' OR gender='$gender2')
```

You can additionally read about operators [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html).

Comment: @SaadatEsmaeily Although adding parenthesis will 'fix' your query, please check the comment by Jay Blanchard

Comment: A little explanation of the solution would be helpful to future readers.